# Java technical conflict

Tags: java, class

I have this question in my online QUIZ since i am doing my degree part-time i have very few friends who are not even taking my course. So i am in a bit of confusion here...

This is the question that i have

```
Which of the following statement regarding class in Java is true:
Answer

A class is made of objects

A class is used as a template to create objects

A class supplies or delivers objects to the rest of the application 

A class is a collection of objects
```

So I am thinking the answer is

```
A class is used as a template to create objects
```

I will explain why i am thinking that way, this is because, even the mainmethod is in a class and it is indeed a template.. that is why. But my spider senses telling me to choose the longest answer (a nifty trick that helped me some times).
So what do you experts think? and please dont negative this question..if it is not appropriate please comment it and then i will close it.. tks

Comment: None of the 4 proposals looks well formulated to me...

Comment: well this have to do as these are the options i have to choose from.

Comment: I agree with assylias, none of these is how the term "class" is commonly used.

Comment: A class can be made of objects, can be a collection of objects, can be used as a template. A class object (I'm stretching it) can also supply objects to the rest of the application: `String.class.getMethods();`. On the other hand, a utility class with a private constructor can't be used to create objects, unless it has extra methods... Very confusing...

Comment: @assylias my tots exactly.. so all the answers are so contradicting

Comment: A "class" is a category to which objects can belong. Just like "armored vehicle" is a class to which particular vehicles can belong. (Though, oddly, a class can act even if no objects belong to it.)

Comment: I just noticed this as I was retagging it.  The description for the class tag answers the question: "Construct that is used as template for creating new objects. Class describes the state and behavior that the objects of the class all share."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is true, as a class provides the behaviour and structure for all instances created from it. (Note, however, that "template" in the context of programming usually means something different, see, e.g. templates in C++.)

The first sentence is false -- the class can exist without any instances (consider, for example, a static class).

The third sentence is false -- this would be a description of a Factory method or a Factory object (look for the Factory pattern in Wikipedia).

The fourth sentence is false -- classes need not be collections. There are classes that provide the functionality of collections (e.g. lists or maps or sets), but these are particular classes -- there are many other ones.

Comment: The class *is* the behavior and structure. The source code for the class defines the behavior and structure.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. But `main` is not a good example because it is `static` (so, no object of its class must be created for it to be invoked).

The reasoning is that for creating a new object, you do:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

And that by, myObject will have all the methods and properties defined in MyClass.

Comment: if thats the case then you mean to say that 
"A class is NOT a collection of objects "?

Comment: A class is not a collection of objects. There are some classes whose instances are collections of objects.

Comment: A class has never been a collection of objects. A class is used to define object behavior.